# What does rtp2xyz do?

Tags: pstricks

A number of three-dimensional pstricks examples include the line `rtp2xyz`, which is applied to three numbers that look like angles (specified in degrees). What exactly does it do?  While I'm at it, what does `Decran` do, since these often seem to appear together?

Comment: Looks like [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Comment: @SeanAllred: Obviously, but what *exactly* does it do? In particular, why do all three numbers tend to look like angles and/or zero?  Or is this just my imagination?

Comment: I'm not a PSTricks expert by any stretch of the imagination, but without any context it's hard to even conjecture.  A search for `rtp2xyz` turned up nothing from within `texdoc pstricks`; could you post a model example from your resource?  (Also, I found [this nonsense-to-me mail](http://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2007/004290.html) on the list.)

Comment: `texdoc pst-solides3d` explains both `Decran` and `rtp2xyz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rtp2xyz`: Radius,Theta,Phi->x,y,z

The viewpoint is the distance from the eye to the object and `Decran` is the distance from the object to the plane on which the object is projected.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the definition of `rtp2xyz` in Postscript (from [`pst-solides3d.pro`](http://texnik.dante.de/dvips/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d.pro)):

```
%%%%% ### trigospherique ### 
%% passage spherique --> cartesiennes
%% les formules de passage ont été récupérées ici :
%%    http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordonn%C3%A9es_polaires
%% syntaxe : r theta phi rtp2xyz -> x y z
/rtp2xyz {
6 dict begin
   /phi exch def
   /theta exch def
   /r exch def
   /x phi cos theta cos mul r mul def 
   /y phi cos theta sin mul r mul def
   /z phi sin r mul def
   x y z
end
} def
```

It is used to convert [spherical coordinates (r,t,p)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to [Cartensian (x,y,z)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in 3D.

For `Decran`, see section **2.2. The definition of the option `Decran`** (p 14) of the [`pst-solides3d` documentation](http://texnik.dante.de/doc/generic/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf). It contains example of how the value of `Decran` affect the display.